# hiveQL if statements regroup on one row

Tags: hive, hiveql

Query :

```
select IF(type='view', count(*), 0), IF(type='click', count(*), 0)
from ad_events
where year=2013 and month=01 and day=18 and (hour=01 or hour=02)
group by type
```

Result :

```
      _c0       _c1
0      0         0
1      0         0
2      0       1368
3      0         0
4      0         0
5      0         0
6      0         0
7      0         0
8   277917       0
9      0         0
```

Is there anyway to have the result only on one row like that ? :

```
      _c0       _c1
0    277917     1368
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I just did it in a nested query :

```
select SUM(c), SUM(v)
from (
select tracking_id, IF(type='view', count(*), 0) AS v, IF(type='click', count(*), 0) AS c
from ad_events
where year=2013 and month=01 and day=18
group by tracking_id, type
) t2
```

Comment: thanks - I never thought of doing the count inside the "IF" before. The reason you got so many "empty" rows  is that there was (probably) 10 different possible values for "type", and you are grouping by "type", but not selecting it. That doesn't stop the grouping, and it looks like you have too many results. But the subquery takes care of that. Thanks

Comment: hm, IF in aggreagation doesn't work for me, I get "Expression not in GROUP BY key '0'"

Answer (score 2):

Please try following

```
select
   type,
   count(type) TypeCount
from ad_events
where
   year=2013 and 
   month=01 and 
   day=18 and 
   (hour=01 or 
    hour=02)
group by type
```